# Exact resource type name for String Table

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource, string-table

What is the exact name of the String Table Resource Type (such as BITMAP, etc)? I'm using Visual Basic.

I've searched and I can't find anything regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really the way it works.  Each string you put in the string table will become a property.  Of the Resources module.  You access them in your code with My.Resources.Foo for a string named "Foo".

You can see all this by putting the Solution Explorer window into guru mode.  Click the Show All Files icon in the toolbar at the top of the Solution Explorer window.  You'll now see everything that's part of your project, including the auto-generated files.  Open the My Project node, the Resources.resx node and double-click the Resources.Designer.vb node.  You'll see the code that is auto-generated from the resources you entered.  Don't edit the file.

Comment: I'm using a block of code to Assign a certain resource to a Byte Array. The problem is that i'm using the code `Dim buf As Byte() = resourceManager.Read("STRINGTABLE", "binUC.exe")` and I need to specify a resource type (Parameter 1) and then Parameter 2 is the file. However, the byte array is reading as null when I use this code.

Comment: ResourceManager doesn't have a method named "Read".  I don't have a clue what you are talking about or what problem you are trying to solve with that statement.

Comment: resourceManager.Read is a custom function. I'm trying to extract strings from an external executable.